# Installing Channels: Python Django version and settings

Tags: python, django, installation, twisted, django-channels

I'm trying to add `Channels` to my app by following this tutorial:
https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django

The Django app compiles, but when I try to run it:

```
(virtualenv) root@computer:path# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It gives error:

```
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 75, in resolve_routing
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import channel routing %r: %s" % (routing, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import channel routing 'codebench.routing.channel_routing': cannot import name ProtocolTypeRouter
```

According to this
https://github.com/VincentTide/django-channels-celery-example/issues/1
It maybe related to Python version, so I did:

```
(virtualenv) root@computer:path# alias python=python3
(virtualenv) root@computer:path# python -V
Python 3.5.2
(virtualenv) root@computer:path# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    import eventlet
ImportError: No module named 'eventlet'
(virtualenv) root@computer:path# pip install eventlet
Requirement already satisfied: eventlet in /root/.virtualenvs/codebench/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.3 in /root/.virtualenvs/codebench/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet)
Requirement already satisfied: enum-compat in /root/.virtualenvs/codebench/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from eventlet)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34 in /root/.virtualenvs/codebench/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from enum-compat->eventlet)
```

Now I stuck at: `ImportError: No module named 'eventlet'`

I have the following packages installed:

```
channels==1.1.6
daphne==1.4.0
Django==1.9
eventlet==0.20.0
```

If I follow this tutorial: http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/getting-started.html

```
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
February 16, 2018 - 23:19:32
Django version 1.9, using settings 'codebench.settings'
Starting Channels development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Channel layer default (asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer)
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-02-16 23:19:32,935 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 23:19:32,935 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 23:19:32,935 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
2018-02-16 23:19:32,936 - INFO - worker - Listening on channels http.request, websocket.connect, websocket.disconnect, websocket.receive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 457, in fire_timers
    timer()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 58, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 145, in _do_acquire
    waiter.switch()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/green/thread.py", line 41, in __thread_body
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 99, in inner_run
    websocket_handshake_timeout=self.websocket_handshake_timeout,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 101, in run
    websocket_handshake_timeout=self.websocket_handshake_timeout
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy_forwarded_proto_header'
```

---

If I upgrade everything, except Python 2.7.12:

```
asgi-redis==1.4.3
asgiref==2.1.5
channels==2.0.2
daphne==2.0.3
Django==1.11.10
```

`runserver` will give:

```
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/channels/apps.py", line 6, in <module>
    import daphne.server  # noqa
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/codebench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 192
    async def handle_reply(self, protocol, message):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I try to reinstall all required packages under Python 3.5.2:

Need this for `twisted`:

```
apt install python3.6-dev
```

https://askubuntu.com/questions/966939/failed-building-wheel-for-twisted

Now I'm getting random errors:

```
2018-02-18 14:03:51,634 - ERROR - server - Exception inside application: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'writeSequence'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 191, in __call__
    await self.handle(body)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 108, in __call__
    return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 373, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 361, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 296, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 123, in thread_handler
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/http.py", line 227, in handle
    self.send(response_message)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 62, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 405, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 76, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 196, in handle_reply
    protocol.handle_reply(message)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daphne/http_protocol.py", line 210, in handle_reply
    http.Request.write(self, message.get("body", b""))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1084, in write
    self.channel.writeSequence(toChunk(data))
  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'writeSequence'
```

Also:

```
(python3) root@computer:path# python manage.py shell
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import channels
>>> print(channels.__file__)
/root/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/__init__.py
>>> from channels import Group
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Group'
```

Comment: That tutorial is nearly a couple of years old. You can't expect it to work any more. Note that Channels 2 has just been released and there are [some significant changes](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/one-to-two.html). You might be better to start with Channel 2 so that you don't have to make changes later.

Comment: That tutorial work with channels 1.8, Can you post the code of routing.py of your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with the following versions:

```
asgi-redis==0.8.3
asgiref==0.9
autobahn==0.12.1
channels==0.9.3
daphne==0.9.1
dj-database-url==0.4.0
Django==1.9.3
haikunator==1.0.1
msgpack-python==0.4.7
psycopg2==2.7.4
redis==2.10.5
six==1.10.0
Twisted==15.5.0
txaio==2.2.1
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Turned out Python version doesn't matter, works with both 2.7 and 3.5.
Because I was installing the https://github.com/jacobian/channels-example,
I also changed the database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. This example works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you created a Python 2 virtualenv. Setting `alias python=python3` won't work. You need to create a virtualenv using Python 3, for example:

```
python3 -m venv newenv
```

Then re-install your requirements in the new virtualenv.

Once you have activated the new environment, `python` will be `python3`. You won't need to set `alias python=python3`.